# Javascript blob window open fires browser popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a download operation in my javascript code with `angularjs` `$http` provider.

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:28494/api/print",
    data: data,
    responseType:'arraybuffer'
}).then(
    function (response) {

        var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});

        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        window.open(objectUrl,'_blank');         
    }
);
```

This fires my browser popup. I do not want to this.

[image]

But I want to download directly. Do not show the popup.

Comment: try `window.location = objectUrl`

Comment: You could use an invisible iframe? Like [here][1] [1] http://stackoverflow.com/a/3749395/3577695

Comment: @bookmarker, which solution helped you? Please upvote/accept the right solution(s).

Comment: @ArshadRehmani no one.

Comment: can't change file name? why Hexadecimal?

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`window.location.assign(objectUrl);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign). This forces the window to open and display the url. In your case it will download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative approach.

```
window.location = item.objectUrl;
```

This will cause the browser to request a resource from the server, the response from server must include `Content-Disposition:attachment;`. It will cause the browser to show download dialog.

P.S. When you want to force the browser to show download prompt for some file (resource), you must include `Content-Disposition:attachment;` in the response.